# How do I make an image go below another image?

Tags: html, css

I have attempted solutions I have found online, such as introducing div tags and breaks in my html coding around the images, but it did not work. I also attempted to put a general display block in my css style underneath img{ } and this did not work. The breaks only work if I include about 30 of them.

```css
img{
        display: block;
    }
    .img1{
        float: left;
        margin: 15px;
        image-rendering: auto;
        image-rendering: crisp-edges;
        image-rendering: pixelated;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        max-height: 500px;
        max-width: 650px;;
        border-radius: 30%;
    }
    #Ciri{
        image-rendering: auto;
        image-rendering: crisp-edges;
        image-rendering: pixelated;
        max-height: 425px;
        max-width: 500px;
        border: 3px solid #000000;
        border-radius: 150px;
```

```html
<div>

            <img src="images/Paella.jpg" class="img1">
            <p>For the assignment I chose to use a photo of a dish I cooked, Spanish Paella. It was a surprisingly easy dish that did not require a lot of cooking time, and I was quite happy with how it turned out. I uploaded my own image to <a href="https://imgur.com/sILzjLe" target="blank"> imgur </a> for the assignment. </p>

            <br>
            I did struggle to get the image to not be blurry, so I credit <a href="https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/i/image-rendering/" target="blank"> this site </a> which helped maintain the image clarity.    
            </p>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
            <a href="https://imgur.com/Zf6pY9E" target="blank">
            <img id="Ciri" src="images/Ciri.jpg"></a>
        </div>
```

Comment: If you are trying to make an image appear "below" another as if they are stacked on top of each other, you should try using `z-index` and `position: absolute`

Comment: Its not so much I want it underneath the image in the literal sense, but I want it to appear below it like. There's an image, and then directly below it is the other image, as opposed to side by side.

Comment: Could you include an image showing what your current code is doing? I believe by default images are placed on separate lines?

Comment: Here's an imgur link of how its appearing https://imgur.com/R6S9Uxg

Comment: ah, in that case, you can try including `style: "display: block"` in the <img> tags of each image

Comment: can you include an image of the code breaking with a lot of images? It seems that using `display: block` would work unless there's some other underlying circumastances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just have to arrange your stylings, like if that image contains a description or alike, try enclosing it with an "div". But if it's only pure images, then you can make the display of that `img` to block. See sample snippet.

```css
img.block {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" class="block">
  
  <div>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x200/000/fff">
    <p>
    this is an image that has a caption
    </p>
  <div>
</div>
```

**Update**

If you want it to be flexible, just put it inside `<div>` tag coz by default it is set already as `block`.

```
<div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" class="block">
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x200/000/fff">
    <p>
    this is an image that has a caption
    </p>
  <div>
</div>
```

If that doesn't work, then perhaps you might have an existing CSS that causes conflicts or overrides the styles. Can you post it?

Comment: I attempted your solution and it does work only if the image with the paragraph can be underneath the first image with no content. Is there a way to have it so the first image can have the paragraph?

Comment: kindly check my updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

There are so many ways to achieve this, a little dirty trick is to use a break:

```
<img src="url" /><br>
<img src="url" />
```

You could also use blocks:

```
<style> img { display: block }</style>
```

You could use div (dividers):

```
<div><img src="url" /></div>
<div><img src="url" /></div>
```

You may also want try using `z-index` and `position: absolute`.

Comment: This was not working, I have already tried using div tags, and also using the <br> in my html code between the two image sources.

Comment: @AndrewOvers you might want to use ```img.block {
  display: block;
}
<div>
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" class="block">
  
  <div>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x200/000/fff">
    <p>
    this is an image that has a caption
    </p>
  <div>
</div>```.
from @jrran90.